# How to logout using OAuth2 Facebook client flow?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

How to logout from facebook app using oauth2 client flow?

I failed to find any way to do it in official docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: I guess you can try the PHP-SDK [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) just to check how the getLogoutUrl() looks like. Or check how to it's formed [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L498).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't really need to logout, because webview which is used for client flow, doesn't store logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Javascript SDK by calling FB.logout. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

I'm not sure how to do this without using one of the official SDKs however.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the new PHP-SDK, you need to both call FB.logout from the JavaScript SDK, and also destroy the user's session on your server, as the new PHP SDK stores user id and access token in a PHP session.

I use:

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the very beginning of your website page

```
session_start();

if($_GET['logoutfrmfb']=="logout")
{
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_code']);
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_access_token']);
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_user_id']);
}
```

Find and edit the following lines in src/base_facebook.php (probably lines 506-515)

```
  public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {
 return $this->getUrl(
   'www',
   'logout.php',
   array_merge(array(
     'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl().'?logoutfrmfb=logout',
     'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
   ), $params)
   );
  }
```

works for me!

Answer (score -2):

Use FB.getLoginStatus and FB.logout JavaScript function.

Comment: Whoever had voted for negative scoring: I had used those functions in actual live site implementation.